# Map rotation field don´t change in Atlas QGIS 2.18.14. Is this a bug?

Tags: qgis, atlas, data-defined-override

I set up Scale and Rotation Map Fields to use with Data defined Override function, in an Atlas.

As I browse the maps in the Atlas, the Scale field appears fine, it change with the data from that field, but the Map rotation field don´t change, and has data in it.

Is this a bug?

I try with several types of fields, and still don´t show the data in it...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that's fine - we use data defined overrides, and the box never reports what is actually being used... maybe something that should change, but I think the setting is being used correctly... for example, if you hard-coded the scale (currently showing correctly) to something different than the value in the expression, what shows up?

Comment: I do not know if I answer your question,@DPSSpatial, but the information shown in the 'Scale' box will change according to the attribute table data. But the same does not happen with the 'Map rotation' box information. In fact, here, the last information entered in the box itself is kept, regardless of the data that is in the attribute table. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R43CI.gif